# CDK scope-error when executing external jobs

Tags: python, scope, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I've created a setup that works to generate state machines, however for some reason it does not work for the two specific `Task`s `GlueStartJobRun` and `StepFunctionsStartExecution`. Here is part of my current setup:

```
.
├── app.py
├── cloudformation
│   ├── stepfunctions.py            # includes `stack`
├── statemachines
│   ├── some_workflow.py
│   └── another_workflow.py
└── ...
```

Inside of the `stepfunctions.py`, i define my stack and a way to generate state machines:

```
import dataclasses
from aws_cdk import aws_stepfunctions
from constructs import Construct

@dataclasses.dataclass
class StateMachineUtil:
    name: str
    definition: aws_stepfunctions.Chain

from aws_cdk import Stack
class StepfunctionStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, env: Environment):
        super().__init__(scope, env=env)
    
    def generate_state_machines(self, state_machines):
        [self.__generate_state_machine(state_machine) for state_machine in state_machines]

    def __generate_state_machine(self, state_machine):
        return aws_stepfunctions.StateMachine(
            scope=self,
            id=f"{state_machine.name}-statemachine",
            definition=state_machine.definition,
            state_machine_name=state_machine.name,
        )
```

Then, i define a function inside the workflow-scripts which returns a `definition`, which is

```
from aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks import CallAwsService
from aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions import Pass    

def generate_some_definition(scope: Construct) -> aws_stepfunctions.Chain:
    step_1 = Pass(
        scope=scope,
        id="some-id",
    )
    step_2 = CallAwsService(
        scope=scope,
        id="another-id",
        service="glue",
        action="GetTable",
        iam=["*"],
        parameters={...}
        result_path="..."
    )
    step_3 = Pass(
        scope=scope,
        id="a-third-id",
    )
    
    return step_1.next(step_2).next(step_3)
```

The script `app.py` should now simply put everything together:

```
from cloudformation.stepfunctions import StepfunctionStack, StateMachineUtil
from statemachines.some_workflow import generate_some_definition 
from statemachines.another_workflow import generate_another_definition

app = aws_cdk.App()
env = aws_cdk.Environment(account=12345, region="eu-west-1")
mystack = StepfunctionStack(scope=app, env=env)

mystack.generate_state_machines(
    [
        StateMachineUtil(name="a-name", definition=generate_some_definition(scope=app)),
        StateMachineUtil(name="another-name", definition=generate_another_definition(scope=app)),
    ]
)
```

This setup works perfectly fine. No problem, i run `cdk synth` and i get no error message. However, if I try to setup a `workflow.py` that uses `StepFunctionsStartExecution` or `GlueStartJobRun`, then i get the error message:

> RuntimeError: StepFunctionsStartExecution at '' should be created in the scope of a Stack, but no Stack found

Here is what the `workflow.py` could look like (same as before, but with 2 added tasks):

```
from aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks import CallAwsService, GlueStartJobRun, StepFunctionsStartExecution
from aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions import Pass, IntegrationPattern, TaskInput  

def generate_some_definition(scope: Construct, crawler_state_machine: aws_stepfunctions.IStateMachine) -> aws_stepfunctions.Chain:
    step_1 = Pass(
        scope=scope,
        id="a-fourth-id",
    )
    step_2 = StepFunctionsStartExecution(
        scope=scope,
        id="Run separate state machine",
        state_machine=separate_state_machine,
        integration_pattern=IntegrationPattern.RUN_JOB,
        input=TaskInput.from_object({...}),
        result_selector={...}
    )
    step_3 = GlueStartJobRun(
        scope=scope,
        id="Run glue job",
        glue_job_name="...",
        integration_pattern=IntegrationPattern.RUN_JOB,
        arguments=TaskInput.from_json_path_at("...")
    )
    step_4 = CallAwsService(
        scope=scope,
        id="another-one-id",
        service="glue",
        action="GetTable",
        iam=["*"],
        parameters={...}
        result_path="..."
    )
    step_5 = Pass(
        scope=scope,
        id="an-eighth-id",
    )
    
    return step_1.next(step_2).next(step_3).next(step_4).next(step_5)
```

And suddenly, it breaks down. Giving me the error message i posted above.

Comment: You'll need to include the code in `...` - that's where the error is. And also include how your `generate_some_definition` function is being used (where and with what arguments).

Comment: hey, thanks for engaging, been struggling with this for so long, i don't understand what's going on. the dots are now updated, should be enough context now. if not please tell me and i'll add more

Comment: As @gshpychka suspected, the problem is in `app.py`.  The scopes in the definition methods should be `mystack`, not `app`: `definition=generate_some_definition(scope=mystack)`.

Comment: oh wow, it worked! write it as an answer and i'll accept it, big thanks. if you have any good link where i can read up on this topic, i would very much appreciate that aswell.

Comment: Glad it's working!  The glory belongs to @gshpychka.  He deserves the credit for solving your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, the `scope` parameter you pass to the `StepFunctionsStartExecution` constructor should contain a stack at some point in the tree.

You are passing an `App`, and there is no `Stack` in the scope, so this fails.

Pass a stack as the scope. Alternatively, pass any construct created within the scope of a stack (or within the scope of a construct created within the scope of a stack - you get the point)